# GTK C - get value of pointer to gint64 to feed the gtk_list_store_set

Tags: c, gtk

I guess i have a pure C problem here and that it has nothing to do with GTK, but i'm not sure.

I have this function in which i'm retreiving the content of a GtkEntry, converting the gchar to gint64 with another function, and then i want to add it to the list. Thou, while the first `printf` gives me the right value, the second one gives an incorrect value.

So, i can't figure out how to pass this value contained in the `*c` to the gtk_list_store_set.

```
    void on_button_add_clicked (GtkButton *button, app_widgets *app_wid) {

        GtkTreeIter iter;

        //get the entry content
        gint64 *c = mult_by_100_char2int(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(app_wid->ent_mont)));
        printf("c=%li\n",*c);
        gint64 cval = *c;
        printf("cval=%li\n",cval);

        //put in the liststore
        GtkListStore *store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(app_wid->treeview)));
        gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);  // Acquire an iterator
        gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter,
            AMOUNT_COLUMN, cval,  //the column requires a gint64
            -1);

    }

//prototype of other function is:
gint64* mult_by_100_char2int (const gchar* number)
```

Edit: (added functions - in reverse order)

```
gint64* mult_by_100_char2int (const gchar* number) {

    const gchar* buf1 = mult_by_100(number);
    gint64 buf2 = g_ascii_strtoll(buf1,NULL,10);
    gint64 *buf3 = &buf2;

    return buf3;

}

gchar* mult_by_100 (const gchar *number) {

    int thesize = strlen(number);

    gchar *entiers = substring(number,0,thesize-3);
    gchar *centimes = substring(number,thesize-2,2);
    gchar *result = g_strjoin("",entiers,centimes,NULL);

    return result;
    g_free(result);
}

gchar* substring(const gchar* s, int p, int l) {

    char sub[128] = "";
    char schar[128] = "";
    gchar* result;
    int i;

    strcat(schar,s);

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
        sub[i] = schar[p+i];
        //printf("i=%d - sub=%s\n",i,sub);
    }
    sub[i+1] = '\0';

    result = g_strdup(sub);
    return result;
    g_free(result);
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you got pointers confused. Can you add the content of function `mult_by_100_char2int`?

Comment: Ok, i've added the 3 nested functions.

Comment: Does `mult_by_100_char2int` need to return a pointer to gint64? Those g_free's after return are completely redundant, they will never be executed...

Comment: Well, i could make that function return a gint64.. that doesn't explain why this doesn't work thou.. Thank you for the comment about the g_free's. I didn't figured out the functions end after a return.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding `g_free(result);` after `return result;` ? Doesn't your compiler tell something about dead/unreachable code?

Comment: Yes, i was not aware of that when i wrote that code, but now i know that is non-sense since a function ends after `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buf3` is an address of a variable local to `mult_by_100_char2int`. This variable does not exist anymore once `mult_by_100_char2int` returns. Your program has no right to access it.

It is an unlucky coincidence that the first `printf` produced a correct result. We may theorize why it did happen (I wouldn't be surprised is removal of first `printf` make the second one appear to work correctly), but the bottomline is that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought a copy of the value was made inside the callback function, but that's not the case for pointers unless it's a const char/gchar...

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic question about pointers, nothing to do, as you stated, with Gtk. The @user58697 answer explain the why this happens.

The solve this problem, the `mult_by_100_char2int` function should return a gint64 instead of a pointer to a local variable.

It should look something like this:

```
gint64 mult_by_100_char2int (const gchar* number) {

    gchar* buf1 = mult_by_100(number);
    gint64 retval = g_ascii_strtoll(buf1,NULL,10);
    g_free (buf1);

    return retval;
}
```

Then, your callback function should be:

```
void on_button_add_clicked (GtkButton *button, app_widgets *app_wid) {

    GtkTreeIter iter;

    //get the entry content
    gint64 c = mult_by_100_char2int(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(app_wid->ent_mont)));
    printf("c=%li\n",c);

    //put in the liststore
    GtkListStore *store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(app_wid->treeview)));
    gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);  // Acquire an iterator
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter,
        AMOUNT_COLUMN, c,  //the column requires a gint64
        -1);

}
```

The other functions, as stated in the comments, have redundant g_free's, so they should be something like this (notice that i've only looked at the `g_free` calls, no other action taken, the code could be improved):

```
gchar* mult_by_100 (const gchar *number) {

    int thesize = strlen(number);

    gchar *entiers = substring(number,0,thesize-3);
    gchar *centimes = substring(number,thesize-2,2);
    gchar *result = g_strjoin("",entiers,centimes,NULL);

    g_free(entiers);
    g_free(centimes);

    return result;
}

gchar* substring(const gchar* s, int p, int l) {

    char sub[128] = "";
    char schar[128] = "";
    gchar* result;
    int i;

    strcat(schar,s);

    for(i=0;i<l;i++) {
        sub[i] = schar[p+i];
        //printf("i=%d - sub=%s\n",i,sub);
    }
    sub[i+1] = '\0';

    result = g_strdup(sub);
    return result;
}
```

Haven't tested the code but it should work now.

Comment: It does indeed runs flawless, thank you. As said above, i were not aware of this specificity of a pointer returning function. According to what i just read on other posts, it's different for char variables as they stay untill the end of the program.